# How to skip unreachable nodes when using knife ssh

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to run a shell command on multiple nodes using `knife ssh` in a following way:

```
knife ssh -V "role:web" --ssh-gateway ec2-user@aws_ssh_gateway \
          --ssh-user ubuntu \
          "sudo chef-client"
```

It works fine when all my instances with role "web" are up, but when I take down only one instance this command hangs with this message:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to  -- Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
```

Is there a way to tell knife to just skip unreachable nodes and continue with ones that are up?

UPDATE: Knife should skip unreachable nodes by default but this does not happen. Possible reason is SSH gateway. Investigating.

Comment: It works as expected for me, skipping the ones that are unreachable, so I'd say that the problem is pretty much one on your environment.

Since you're using a SSH gateway, I'd suggest checking connection to the gateway individually first.

Also (although unrelated), if you're using this GW to reach private subnets on a VPC, allow me to suggest that you install an OpenVPN server on the gateway and use that instead -- much simpler and more reliable IMO.

Comment: @cbl Gateway is fine. And if all nodes that are returned by query are up everything runs smoothly, there is a problem only if one of the nodes goes down. Thanks for your tip on OpenVPN, I think I'll go this route.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

As of Chef 11, knife will just warn and skip unreachable nodes automatically.

Comment: True for 'knife ssh', but not for 'knife winrm' on chef 13